# Pandas create new column with array of other columns with a non null value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
   List1  List2  List3  List4  List5  List6  List7  List8
0    NaN    NaN      1    NaN    NaN    NaN      1    NaN
1    NaN    NaN      1    NaN    NaN    NaN      1    NaN
2    NaN    NaN      1    NaN    1.0    NaN      1    NaN
3    NaN    NaN      1    NaN    NaN    NaN      1    NaN
4    NaN    NaN      1    NaN    1.0    NaN      1    NaN
```

I want to create a new Column called `Lists` which is an array of all the other columns with a non null value. ie:

```
                           Lists
0    ['List3', 'List7']
1    ['List3', 'List7']
2    ['List3', 'List5', 'List7']
3    ['List3', 'List7']
4    ['List3', 'List5', 'List7']
```

I accomplished this with an `iterrows()` loop, but it's not performant at all. Would appreciate any ideas here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `DataFrame.dot` to get all columns which are `notna`:

```
df["Lists"] = df.notna().dot(df.columns+",").str.rstrip(",").str.split(",")
```

```
   List1  List2  List3  List4  List5  List6  List7  List8                  Lists
0    NaN    NaN      1    NaN    NaN    NaN      1    NaN         [List3, List7]
1    NaN    NaN      1    NaN    NaN    NaN      1    NaN         [List3, List7]
2    NaN    NaN      1    NaN   1.00    NaN      1    NaN  [List3, List5, List7]
3    NaN    NaN      1    NaN    NaN    NaN      1    NaN         [List3, List7]
4    NaN    NaN      1    NaN   1.00    NaN      1    NaN  [List3, List5, List7]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly with way better performance! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another version:

```py
df["Lists"] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x.notna()].index.tolist(), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   List1  List2  List3  List4  List5  List6  List7  List8                  Lists
0    NaN    NaN      1    NaN    NaN    NaN      1    NaN         [List3, List7]
1    NaN    NaN      1    NaN    NaN    NaN      1    NaN         [List3, List7]
2    NaN    NaN      1    NaN    1.0    NaN      1    NaN  [List3, List5, List7]
3    NaN    NaN      1    NaN    NaN    NaN      1    NaN         [List3, List7]
4    NaN    NaN      1    NaN    1.0    NaN      1    NaN  [List3, List5, List7]
```

Comment: What's the performance on this (and in general using apply) vs the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.apply` on `axis=1` with a lambda with a list-comprehension and take only the columns that has non-`NaN` value for each row using `pd.notna()`:

```py
>>> df.apply(lambda x: [c for c in df if pd.notna(x[c])], axis=1)

0           [List3, List7]
1           [List3, List7]
2    [List3, List5, List7]
3           [List3, List7]
4    [List3, List5, List7]
dtype: object
```